# How do I hide contacts in HTC Sense?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, contacts, htc-sense, htc-droid-incredible

How do I hide contacts that I sync from Google Contacts in the Sense? I removed them from My Contacts and filed them under an "Archived" group. I want to keep them, but not show up.

I can go to the second "tab" on the bottom to filter by group, but thats a hassle.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an HTC phone but on my Samsung Spica running rooted Eclair (2.1), here's how I restrict a particular group of contacts.

Start the CONTACTS app.

Press MENU > DISPLAY OPTIONS

Select "Show only contacts with phones" (personal prefs)

Below that will be a list of Google accounts linked to the device - each one will have system groups like FAMILY / FRIENDS / COWORKERS / MY CONTACTS etc in addition to user created groups such as "Archived" like you've created.

Just select those you wish to display and leave unchecked the groups you wish to ignore.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have those in Sense. :(

Answer (score 0):

Go to the People application, then press the `menu` button, choose `View`, and fiddle with the checkboxes. You need the first one "Only contacts with phone numbers", but the others could also be of use if you have a lot of different data sources.

This is on HTC Desire with 2.2 Froyo.

Comment: That does not work for me. I want to retain phone numbers for people but not show them in my main contacts list.